# Why I do not get the interaction output using aov function in R

Tags: r, anova, interaction

I hope you are well.

I am analyzing some data related to some bacterial phylum.

Here is the data:

[image]

I am writing the **aov** function as the following but I do not get the **interaction** value.

`acioaov <- aov(Acidobacteria ~ Treatment * Zone, data = phyla)`

Why it doesn't work?

The out put of that is like the following:

`Df   Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)

Treatment    1 0.000106 0.0001063   0.473 0.4986

Zone         6 0.003153 0.0005255   2.338 0.0656 .
Residuals   23 0.005170 0.0002248`

Thank you!

Comment: Hi @StupidWolf Thanks for your comment. I added the data.

Comment: Hi Armin. Just to clarify. I see that in zone u added a subscript nt or t. For example maize nt 21 and maize t 21 are these the same strain?

Comment: Hi @StupidWolf. NT means Not Treated and T means Treated. That is not 21. That is Z1 and "Z" indicates zone. If it's not clear let me know, please.

Comment: I see, hey the reason your anova did not work, is because it does not recognize maize_nt_21 and maize_t_21 as the same zone category so as to say. So what you need to do is to change the way it's named and redo the anova

Comment: @StupidWolf, Thank you very much for your help and your time. Yes it worked.
Just one more question: 
For example, NT_Z1 and T_Z1 are belong to the same zone but there are for two different strain. Can I follow based on your solution? I mean as you said, I removed NT and T from all the Zone column but wouldn't make a problem?  On the other hand, I don't have NT_Z1 and T_Z1 for one strain; it is for two different strain.

Comment: If i get you correct, labelling for example NT_Z1 and T_Z1 as maize_Z1 is correct. They are two different strains / experiments / observations. In your model, you want to account for the effect of zone and treatment on acidobacteria. so the model in my solution is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot really type your data in, but let's suppose your data.frame phyla is something like this:

```
# you don't need to run
phyla = data.frame(Treatment=rep(c("NT","T"),each=4),
Zone=rep(c("maize_NT_Z1","maize_NT_Z2","maize_T_Z1","maize_T_Z2"),each=2)
)
phyla$Acidobacteria = rnorm(nrow(phyla))

summary(aov(Acidobacteria ~ Treatment * Zone, data = phyla))
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
Treatment    1  0.082  0.0824   0.319 0.6022  
Zone         2  3.391  1.6953   6.572 0.0544 .
Residuals    4  1.032  0.2580
```

And you don't see the interaction term. That's because there are two categories under each zone, i.e "maize_NT_Z1" and "maize_T_Z1" are treated as a same category, but in fact, they are from the same zone Z1, so you should have maize_Z1 for both of them. Let's rectify this:

```
phyla$Zone = gsub("_[N]*T","",phyla$Zone)
summary(aov(Acidobacteria ~ Treatment * Zone, data = phyla))

               Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
Treatment       1 0.0824  0.0824   0.319 0.6022  
Zone            1 0.9381  0.9381   3.636 0.1292  
Treatment:Zone  1 2.4525  2.4525   9.507 0.0368 *
Residuals       4 1.0318  0.2580
```

Answer (score 2):

If the categories of one dependent variable is associated with the categories of the other dependent variable, you'll not get the interaction.. For example, if a particular type of treatment is available in only one zone, there is no interaction between the zone and the treatment.

Since you have not provided the information about the categories, I couldn't find any other answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than one observation for each combination of T`reatment` and `Zone`? (Unless you do, you cannot estimated the interaction terms in the aabsence of additional assumptions.) Is your data balanced?

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. 

To answer to your questions:

1- Yes, I do have more than one observation
2- The data is balanced.